# Post to multiple users feed di

Tags: facebook, feed

I'm working on a web application which has the desired functionality of being able to post a message to a selected list of facebook friends' walls.  My code was using the /user-id/feed/ API call to accomplish this functionality, but with the upcoming changes that method won't work anymore.  I've made changes to the site to use the Feed Dialog, but that only allows for posting to a single friend's feed.  Is there no longer a way to post to a selected list of friends' feeds?

Comment: Posting to multiple user's walls has been deprecated because most users report the apps that do it as spam.

Comment: From what I have found in my research, it actually is possible, but the app has to be whitelisted, and there is no way to get whitelisted that I've found.  I guess whitelisted apps are allowed to spam?  That's just silly.

Comment: The only way to get whitelisted is to be an internal Facebook app. Basically, the "whitelisted" message is just another way for the API to tell you that what you're trying to do isn't allowed.

Comment: So, pinterest is an internal Facebook app?  I've read that this issue doesn't happen with pinterest at all.

So I guess the whole "Preferred Developer" stuff doesn't exist anymore, because Facebook's info says that's how you get whitelisted, but that applications are currently closed.